# Every time I want to move the player, the maze paints itself instead only the player

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

In my code every time when I move the player, the all maze paints itself again. I can't add enemies, because when I do so, the screen starts to get crazy and paints istself even faster. 
So here is my code. I am trying to build a game that is actually a maze and mario in it. There will be enemies that will try to attack him and kill him, he has to go to the end of it (green block).

The problem is that 
everytime the player moves the all maze is painting itself again. I will be happy to get some help here.

```
//This is my class
public class Maze extends JFrame{
Enemy e1;
Mario mario;
Coin c1;
int scores=0;
//pathX and pathY are the first cordination of mario player
int pathX= 1;
int pathY =1;  
//The maze conatins 1-blocked, 0-empty place to go.
private int[][] maze =
    {       {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, Globals.MARIO, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, Globals.EXIT, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
    };
public int[][] getMaze() {
    return maze;
}
    public Maze() {
    setTitle("Welcome to mario maze!");
    setSize(640,480);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //mario gets x,y in the maze , width and height, health, speed and scores=0.
    mario=new Mario(pathX,pathY,30, 30,100,3.0f,scores);
    e1= new Enemy(6,4,30,30,100,1.0f,this);
    }

}
//this function call other functions of painting.
public void paint(Graphics g) {
      super.paint(g);
      g.translate(50,50);
      drawMaze(g);
      drawMario(g);
      showMarioDetails(g);
      showCoins(g);
      //e1.paint(g);
      Enemy e2= new Enemy (7,7,30,30,100,1.0f,this);
      //e2.paint(g);

    //  EnemyAttacking(mario,e1 );


}



//This is the function that draws the maze:
public void drawMaze(Graphics g)
{
    //Lets draw the maze now:
      for (int row = 0; row < maze.length; row++)
      {
         for (int col = 0; col < maze[0].length; col++)
         {
            Color color=null;
            switch(maze[row][col])
            {
               case Globals.BLOCKED:
               {
                   g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                   g.drawRect(30*col, 30*row,30,30);
                   g.setColor(Color.BLACK);          
                   g.fillRect(30*col, 30*row,30,30);
                   g.drawImage(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("../images/tree1.png")).getImage(),col*30,row*30,30,30,this);
                   break;
               }
               case Globals.EXIT: color= Color.GREEN; break;
               default: color=Color.WHITE; break;
            }
            if (maze[row][col] !=1)
            {

                g.setColor(color);          
                g.fillRect(30*col, 30*row,30,30);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawRect(30*col,30*row,30,30); 
            }

         }
      }

}
//This is the function that draws mario.
public void drawMario(Graphics g)
{
    mario.setX(pathX);
    mario.setY(pathY);
    if(mario.getHealth()>0)
    {
        g.drawImage(mario.getTexture(), mario.getX()*30,mario.getY()*30,30, 30, this);  
    }
}
protected void processKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
   {
      if (e.getID() != KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED)        //check if the player pressed some button.
      {
         return;
      }
      if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)      //check if the player pressed the right button.
      {  
          if(maze[pathY][pathX+1]!=1)
          {
              pathX++;
              mario.setMarioPic(3);
          }
      }
      else
      if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)       //check if the player pressed the left button.
      {
          if(maze[pathY][pathX-1]!=1)
          {
              pathX--;
              mario.setMarioPic(2);
          }
      }
      else
      if( e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_UP)          //check if the player pressed the up button.
      {
          if(maze[pathY-1][pathX]!=1)
          {
              pathY--;
              mario.setMarioPic(1);
          }
      }
      else
      if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)          //check if the player pressed the down button.
      {
          if(maze[pathY+1][pathX]!=1)
          {
              pathY++;
              mario.setMarioPic(0);
          }
      }
      repaint();
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at how to create a minimal and reproducable example of your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Good advice @Schred, and a tip: `[mre]` in a comment expands to [mre].

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Thanks, I was wondering how everyone else did that. ;)

Comment: The problem is that you have your model, view, and controller all mushed together in one class, instead of separated into more easily manageable classes.

Comment: When I pulled your class into my Eclipse, it had 27 compilation errors.  I thought I might help you, but you're going to have to help yourself first.

Comment: Hi  @GilbertLeBlanc it is not all the code. I have also more classes than this one.

Comment: Thanks all of you!

Comment: *"it is not all the code"* We don't want to see 'all the code' or uncompilable code, but an MRE as suggesting in the first and second comments! Please fix that oversight if you cannot solve this from the tips already offered & decide to [edit] the question.